# UnauthorizedAccessException while running jar on linux machine

Tags: java, linux

I am getting the following stacktrace while running jar file on a linux machine . However it works perfectly on windows machine

```
     Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/servicetag/UnauthorizedAccessException
    at com.montior.activemq.util.MQProperty.loadProperties(MQProperty.java:31)
    at com.montior.activemq.util.MonitorThread.loadProperties(MonitorThread.java:82)
    at com.montior.activemq.util.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:39)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
    Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.sun.servicetag.UnauthorizedAccessException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 4 more
```

And this is my loadProperies() method

```
    public static void loadProperties() throws FileNotFoundException,IOException,ArgumentMissingException {
        props=new Properties();

        // load a properties file
        String path = "./util.properties";
        props.load(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));
        ActiveMqClient.readProperties(props);


}
```

Can anyone please help me with this Exception?

Answer (score 1):

The error is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` caused when looking for the class `com.sun.servicetag.UnauthorizedAccessException`. I can find this class in the file `db/lib/register.jar` in the official Oracle JDK. This leads me to the following possible conclusions:

- You're running with the Oracle JVM under Windows
- You're not running with the Oracle JVM under Linux (It's probably OpenJDK).

According to mvnrepository, you can find the missing class in the [`sysnet-registration.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.scn/sysnet-registration/1.0.2) archive. I used jar-download.com to backtrack from the class name to a jar containing it (not linked as the previous link ended up at a spam farm)

You could try adding that jar to your run-time class-path and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Updated the link to use mvnrepository.com. This is a very particular situation where the class is present in the oracle VM, but not in OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

check do you have appropriate access to run applications like java. Try sudo... By default root has these accesses.

You need to have execute permission on file, you can try.
**chmod +x filename**

Comment: sorry !! sudo not allowed on production server

Comment: ask admin to provide access